# How I install Multi vendor magento marketplace module extension?

Tags: magento

I want to buy Multi vendor magento marketplace to convert my magento into multi vendor magento marketplace.
I have see "Medma Magento Marketplace Module extension" on magento store?

Do you have any previous experience with Medma Magento Marketplace Module extension. 
If yes then please tell me how you Install it?
http://www.medma.net/knowledge-base/Magento-marketplace-module/2-14

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to install any extension :

1)you will get an extension key and than you have to go for

System > Magento connect Manager > and than you can install extension key

visit [here](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_connect.htm) for more details.

also just by copying the folders of extension to your magento folders.

ex : just copy app , skin folders to root of the magenhto using ftp [ for ex : filezilla ]

Answer (score 0):

There few steps which help you to install Medma marketplace extension on Magento store:

- Login to your website as admin and navigate to “System -> Magento
  Connect -> Magento Connect Manager”.
- Choose the downloaded extension zip (Medma marketplace) file and
  click on “Upload” button, under “Direct package file upload” section.
- After completion of installation logout and login again as admin.
  Navigation to Medma -> MarketPlace on the Navigation Menu